# Ember: error.messages does not show server errors on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, active-model-serializers

When trying to create a new record, the `errors.messages` do not render as [described in the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html). That said, the console does render the error `Error: The backend rejected the commit because it was invalid: {email: has already been taken}`.

I have the following in my `ember-cli` app:

**Router**

```
Router.map ->
  this.route 'users/new', path: '/signup'
```

**Route**

```
UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    return @store.createRecord('user')
)
```

**Controller**

```
UsersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  actions:
    save: ->
      @get('model').save()
)
```

**Template**

```
<h2>Sign up!</h2>
<form {{action 'save' on='submit'}}>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  {{input id='email' type='email' placeholder='Enter Login' value=email}}
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  {{input id='password' placeholder='Enter Password' type='password' value=password}}
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>

{{#each errors.messages}}
  <p>{{message}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

On the server, I'm using AMS with the following Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(permitted_params(params[:user]))

    if user.save
      render json: user
    else
      render_validation_errors user.errors
    end
  end

  private

  def permitted_params(params)
    params.permit(:email, :password)
  end

  def render_validation_errors errors
    render json: {errors: errors.to_h}, status: 422
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ember Data docs are out of date, they are busy trying to finish up 1.0.  You must be using the `ActiveModelAdapter` (not the RESTAdapter):

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```

And the json returned should be like this

```
 {
    errors:
    {
       foo:'The world is ending!',
       bar:'Error Error Error'
    }
 }
```

And preferably you should wrap your each statement with an if

```
{{#if errors}}
  {{#each errors.messages}}

  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Here's an example, click save with fields blank:

http://jsbin.com/motuvaye/24/edit

Additionally you can extend the rest adapter and add the functionality there, I talked about it here: [Ember Data model's errors property (DS.Errors) not populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027053/ember-data-models-errors-property-ds-errors-not-populating/24027443#24027443)

Comment: I am using the `ActiveModelAdapter`. I get JSON returned that reads: `{ "errors": { "email": "can't be blank", "password": "can't be blank" } }`. Something else must be awry here.

Comment: I also tried, per your example, moving the `save` action into the `UsersNewRoute`, passing in `user` to the function, but to no avail.

Comment: Ah, not doing `.then()` and working with the promises was the last thing that did it for me.