# Ember Data model's errors property (DS.Errors) not populating

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data and I can't seem to get the model's 'errors' property to populate with the error messages from my REST API.  I'm pretty much following the example at this guide:

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html

My app looks like this:

```
    window.App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.User = DS.Model.extend({
        username: DS.attr('string'),
        email: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return this.store.createRecord('user', {
                username: 'mike',
                email: 'invalidEmail'
            });
        },

        actions: {
            save: function () {
                this.modelFor(this.routeName).save();
            }
        }
    });
```

And my API returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 125

{
  "errors": {
    "username": ["Username is taken!"],
    "email": ["Email is invalid."]
  }
}
```

After I call save() on the model, here is what I see on the user model:

```
user.get('isError') // true
user.get('errors.messages') // []
```

Even though the model is registering the isError property correctly, I can't seem to get the error messages to populate.  How can I get this to work?  I'm working on the latest beta build of Ember Data version 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a

Comment: Are you using the ActiveModelAdapter?

Comment: No, I'm using the default DS.RESTAdapter.  At least that's what I think I'm using.  All of my JavaScript code is listed in my question.  I think Ember Data defaults to DS.RESTAdapter if I don't specify anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docs are definitely lacking in this area, the errors aren't populated unless you're using the active model adapter.

Here's an example of it working, also check out [Ember: error.messages does not show server errors on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975722/ember-error-messages-does-not-show-server-errors-on-save/23976364#23976364) where I say the same thing

http://jsbin.com/motuvaye/24/edit

You can fairly easily implement it on the RESTAdapter by overriding `ajaxError` and copying how the active model adapter does it.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {


    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
      var response = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText),
          errors = {};

      if (response.errors !== undefined) {
        var jsonErrors = response.errors;

        Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach(Ember.keys(jsonErrors), function(key) {

          errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key];
        });
      }
      return new DS.InvalidError(errors);
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/motuvaye/27/edit

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js#L102

Comment: Wow, I just wasted hours on this.  Thank you for clarifying this problem.  Do you know if this is a feature of ActiveModelAdapter only by design?  Or are they planning on porting it over to RESTAdapter?

Comment: It might as well be, I think it was originally put their due to built in nature of rails active model adapter (I'm not sure, I don't use it) At the very least it might as well be documented, it's fairly simple to implement on the rest adapter. I'll add the code above.

Comment: in your jsbin example, do you know why Ember Data completely ignores the "base":"General error message here" part of your errors object?  It seems that it only pays attention to the properties that are part of the model, which is a real shame.

Comment: Yeah, currently it only allows errors that have the same name as a defined attribute or relationship on the model (super weird), but that's going away with https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1984

Comment: I added a delete option to your jsbin.  Do you know why isSaving remains true when deleting returns an error from the server?  You can test this by first clicking 'Create' and then clicking 'Delete' here: http://jsbin.com/motuvaye/32/edit

Answer (score 8):

I've had a long and very frustrating experience with Ember Data's errors.messages property, so I thought I'd summarize all of my findings here in case anyone else tries to use this feature.

**1) Documentation is out of date**

As @kingpin2k mentioned in his answer, the documentation at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html is out of date.  The example they provide on that page only works if you're using DS.ActiveModelAdapter.  If you're using the default DS.RESTAdapter, then you need to do something like this.  Note that I prefer this simpler approach instead of just copying ActiveModelAdapter's ajaxError implementation:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajaxError: function (jqXHR) {

        this._super(jqXHR);

        var response = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        if (response.errors)
            return new DS.InvalidError(response.errors);
        else
            return new DS.InvalidError({ summary: 'Error connecting to the server.' });
    }
});
```

**2) You must supply a reject callback**

This is very strange, but when you call save() on your model, you need to provide a reject callback, otherwise, you'll get an uncaught 'backend rejected the commit' exception and JavaScript will stop executing.  I have no idea why this is the case.

Example without reject callback.  This will result in an exception:

```
    user.save().then(function (model) {
        // do something
    });
```

Example with reject callback.  Everything will work well:

```
    user.save().then(function (model) {
        // do something
    }, function (error) {
        // must supply reject callback, otherwise Ember will throw a 'backend rejected the commit' error.
    });
```

**3) By default, only the error properties that are part of the model will be registered in errors.messages.**  For example, if this is your model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

...and if this is your error payload:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "firstName":"is required",
        "summary":"something went wrong"
    }
}
```

Then summary will not appear in user.get('errors.messages').  The source of this problem can be found in the adapterDidInvalidate method of Ember Data.  It uses this.eachAttribute and this.eachRelationship to restrict the registration of error messages to only those that are part of the model.

```
  adapterDidInvalidate: function(errors) {
    var recordErrors = get(this, 'errors');
    function addError(name) {
      if (errors[name]) {
        recordErrors.add(name, errors[name]);
      }
    }

    this.eachAttribute(addError);
    this.eachRelationship(addError);
  }
```

There's a discussion about this issue here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1877

Until the Ember team fixes this, you can work around this problem by creating a custom base model that overrides the default adapterDidInvalidate implementation, and all of your other models inherit from it:

Base model:

```
App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
    adapterDidInvalidate: function (errors) {
        var recordErrors = this.get('errors');
        Ember.keys(errors).forEach(function (key) {
            recordErrors.add(key, errors[key]);
        });
    }
});
```

User model:

```
App.User = App.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**4) If you return DS.InvalidError from the adapter's ajaxError (the one we overrode above), then your model will be stuck in 'isSaving' state and you won't be able to get out of it.**

This problem is also the case if you're using DS.ActiveModelAdapter.

For example:

```
    user.deleteRecord();
    user.save().then(function (model) {
        // do something
    }, function (error) {

    });
```

When the server responds with an error, the model's isSaving state is true and I can't figure out to reset this without reloading the page.

**Update: 2014-10-30**
For anyone who's struggling with DS.Errors, here's a great blog post that summarizes this well: http://alexspeller.com/server-side-validations-with-ember-data-and-ds-errors/

Comment: Thanks for this! It also looks like issue #4 may have been addressed here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1889

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: Ember Data 2.x**

The above response are still somewhat relevant and generally pretty helpful but are now outdated for Ember Data 2.x(v2.5.1 at time of this writing). Here are a few things to note when working with newer versions of Ember Data:

- `DS.RESTAdapter` no longer has an `ajaxError` function in 2.x. This is now handled by [`RESTAdapter.handleResponse()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_handleResponse). You can override this method if any special handling or formatting of errors is required.  [RESTAdapter.handleResponse source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.1/addon/adapters/rest.js#L803)
- The documentation for `DS.Errors` and `DS.Model.errors`(which is an instance of DS.Errors) is currently a little misleading. *It ONLY works when errors in the response adhere to the JSON API error object specification*. This means it will not be at all helpful or usable if your API error objects follow any other format. Unfortunately this behavior can't currently be overridden well like many other things in Ember Data as this behavior is handle in private APIs inside of Ember's InternalModel class within DS.Model.
- `DS.InvalidError` will only be used if the response status code is `422` by default. If your API uses a different status code to represent errors for invalid requests you can override `RESTAdapter.isInvalid()` to customize which status codes(or other part of an error response) to check as representing an `InvalidError`.
- As an alternative you can override `isInvalid()` to always return false so that Ember Data will always create a more generic [`DS.AdapterError` instead](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_adapterError). This error is then set on `DS.Model.adapterError` and can be leveraged as needed from there.
- `DS.AdapterError.errors` contain whatever was returned on the `errors` key of the API response.