# Server side errors not populated in Ember model with RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

While trying to handle server side errors in Ember application, I am unable to show the errors in templates as the model is not populated with the received errors.

Versions used:
Ember-cli: 2.4.3
Ember-data: 2.4.2
adapter: RESTAdapter

The template file contains the form for user sign-up as shown:

```
    {{input type="text" value=username }}  
    {{#each model.errors.username as |error|}}  
         {{error.message}}  
    {{/each}}  
    {{input type="text" value=email }}  
    <button {{action 'register'}}>Register</button>
```

The routes file contains the action 'register' to save the user:

```
register: function(){  
    var username = this.controller.get('username');  
    var email = this.controller.get('email');  
    var user = this.store.createRecord('user',{  
            email: email,  
            username: username  
        });  
    user.save().then(function(){  
        //handle success  
     },function(error){  
       //handle error  
     });  
 });
```

The model looks like:

```
export default Model.extend({  
    email: attr(),  
    username: attr()  
});
```

The API I am using responds with a status 422 and error as shown:

```
{    
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "detail":"can't be blank",
         "source":{  
            "pointer": "/data/attributes/username"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

According to the docs of [DS.Errors](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html) Errors can be displayed by accessing their property name to get an array of all the error objects for that property. And that is what I am trying to do in my template file.
Also I tried accessing the messages property on the error object without success.

```
{{#each model.errors.messages as |message|}}
    {{message}}
{{/each}}
```

When I try to log in console the length property on errors i.e

```
 user.save().then(function(){  
        //handle success  
     },function(error){  
       //handle error  
       console.log(user.get('errors.length'));
     });
```

It always gives me 0. However

```
console.log(user.get('errors.username.length'));
```

gives the desired output, but still the errors are not visible in the template.
Tried overriding ajaxError in RESTAdapter as mentioned in this post [24027053](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027053/ember-data-models-errors-property-ds-errors-not-populating) but no luck.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error lies within:

```
user.save().then(function(){  
    //handle success  
 },function(error){  
   //handle error  
   console.log(user.get('errors.length'));
 });
```

The user is not saved, therefore it has no error. Try this:

```
 user.save().then(function(){  
    //handle success  
 },function(error){  
   //handle error --> how do you handle it? Are you maybe overriding the default behaviour?
   // you might want to put a 'debugger;' statement here in order to see, what the response actually looks like  
   console.log(error.errors);
 });
```

Comment: I am not overriding default behaviour, actually I am unable to implement the default behaviour. As I have mentioned twice in my question that the problem is in displaying errors in template.
console.log(user.get('errors.username'));  gets the error for username also error.errors fetches the desired result. But they can't be displayed in template.
model.errors.username , model.errors or simply errors.username doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by setting up the model with the errors. Looks like DS.Errors doesn't set up the model after the errors get populated.

Now my register function looks like:

```
var route = this;
user.save().then(function(){  
        //handle success  
     },function(error){  
       var errors = user.get('errors');
       route.set('_model.errors',errors);
     });
```

and the model hook in routes file is:

```
_model:{},
model(){
return this.get('_model');
}
```

The register function populates the _model with the errors and the model hook returns _model so that it is available in the views.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best way but this is what worked for me:

```
        save(model) {
        model.save()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('success');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            if (model.get('errors.messages.length') > 0) {
                model.get('errors.messages').forEach((message) => {
                    console.log(message);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('failed');
            }
        });
    }
```

In the template I could access the errors via

```
{{#each model.errors.messages as |error|}}
  <div class="error">
    {{error}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This was a problem in earlier versions that the errors were not populated correctly in the model and so they were not accessible in templates. However in later, the problem has been fixed.